# Impact of number of environment variables on process startup time

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, environment-variables, time

I am exporting 30,000 environment variables before starting up a process and I see a huge start  up time for the process.

```
uruddarraju$ for i in {1..30000}; do export KUBE_SVC_${i}=443; export KUBE_SVC_HOST_$i=192.162.0.1; done;
uruddarraju$ time git clone https://****:x-oauth-basic@github.com/uruddarraju/rnpcinode
-sh: /usr/bin/git: Argument list too long

real    0m25.038s
user    0m24.829s
sys     0m0.096s
```

EDIT 1:
Without the environment variables

```
time git clone https://****:x-oauth-basic@github.com/uruddarraju/node
Cloning into 'node'...
remote: Counting objects: 131, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 131 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 122
Receiving objects: 100% (131/131), 126.46 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (26/26), done.

real    0m0.433s
user    0m0.059s
sys     0m0.075s
```

I was wondering how the number of environment variables would impact a process completion time from start to end.

Comment: @Seth, added my edit. It takes significantly lesser time.

Comment: Well, as you can see that with your first try you get an argument list exception, it's likely that you have different behavior for the application before and after you execute it. This might be caused by the application and not a general problem. If you look at [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) it shouldn't. But you could try one of the debug options to get a grasp on what actually happens.

Comment: Reduce number of variables until you don't get an error, then compare - the error screws up the comparison. Having to copy environment variables to subprocesses does at *some* overhead, but it shouldn't be noticable under normal circumstances.